# Variable length string duplication in Python

Tags: python, duplicates, variable-length-array

The following short `python` script:

```
var1 = '7f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002'

var2 = '01'

output = 'evm --code ' + var1 + var1 + var2 + ' run'

print(output)
```

Is capable of generating the following string:

```
evm --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000201 run
```

However, I'd like to generate strings wherein `var1` can be appended to the leftmost side of the output string for a pre-specified (*parameterized*) number of times. Corresponding to each time we append `var1` to the leftmost side, I'd like to append `var2` to the rightmost side the same number of times.

So with the above output string as a baseline, if we select `3` as our parameter, our new `output` string should render as follows:

```
evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000201010101 run
```

How could I control the duplication of those strings, appending them to that base string as described above, with a variable?

Comment: Python overloads the `*` operator such that multiplying a `String` with an `Int` repeats the string. As such, you are after `(var1 * n) + (var2 * n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multiplier operator on a string, e.g.:

```
repeat = 3
output = 'evm --code ' + var1 * repeat + var2 * repeat + ' run'
```

Comment: but the thing is- `var1` should always be 1 less than `var2`, for some reason in this script they were equivalent

Comment: this works `output = 'evm --code ' + var1 * repeat + var2 * (repeat - 1) + ' run'`

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can multiply a string by an int to repeat it a given number of times:

```
someString = "01"
someInt = 3
someString * someInt
```

will output:

```
'010101'
```

Knowing that, your problem should be trivial to solve. For example:

```
output = "evm --code %s%s run" % (var1 * n, var2 * n)
```

with `n` being a positive integer.

*Note*: above, I use a *string format*, which is better in many ways (and less error prone) than simple concatenation.

Comment: hmm, but the thing is `var1` should always be 1 less than `var2`

Comment: so ? just use `n-1` or some other logic to get the right amount of `var1` and `var2` repetitions.